# rtsp client stream to server

Tags: java, android, streaming, live, rtsp

I am trying to stream (live rtsp) from a java (android) client to a darwin streaming server.

I searched the internet but i couldn't find out how to do this.

What i am trying to do first is to call SETUP.

What i send is this:

```
SETUP rtsp://user:password@ip/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 1
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=0-1
User-Agent: RtspClient
```

and i get:

```
RTSP/1.0 415 Unsupported Media Type
Server: DSS/6.0.3 (Build/526.3; Platform/Linux; Release/Darwin Streaming Server; State/Development; )
Cseq: 1
Connection: Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a valid Transport Header and your missing a new line before the CSeq Header.

Check out this article for some guidance...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

It includes a link to a open project with source code for you to follow.